# Rotated component matrix in Python

Tags: python, pca

I have a 10 components and would like to know the loading of each component (from 56 variables used)

as I use `pca.components_` and compare the highest correlation score with all 56 variables, there are several components that didn't get its loadings.

is it because I didn't do : `pca.components_.T * np.sqrt(pca.explained_variance_)` ?

How we can get rotated component matrix in Python (as we get like output in SPSS)?

Comment: Please take a look on [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and feel free to resubmit the question with a better description of your problem, as well as what you've tried so far, and the errors you have encountered. This will greatly increase the probability of a good answer

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I edited your question improving the formatting. You may also want to add some code: check [mcve]. You're more likely to get help if you can clearly identify your problem, and give other users an easy way to reproduce it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The things I ask more into visualization of loadings for PCA. Which I find out that it was a set of array as explained in https://datascience-enthusiast.com/Python/PCA_Spark_Python_R.html

and loadings itself is actually pca.component_